Vertical alignment not centered in tabularray
To present some pictograms, I use a tabularray table and the packages providing me the pictograms (ghsystem and isosafety). I don't understand why the text is not vertically centered

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,3cm]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH09 & \ghspic{aqpol} & Danger pour l'environnement\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers pour l'environnement}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_environnement}
    \end{table}

\end{document}


By inserting pictograms in adjustbox with option valign=c which move pictograms baseline to their vertical center:
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{%amsmath,
                booktabs,
                %counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth
                }
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{
%   vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
        colsep=3pt,
        colspec={Q[c,2cm] Q[c,3cm] Q[c,3cm]}, 
%   rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
        row{1}={font=\bfseries},
        }
        \toprule[blue]
        Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
        \midrule[blue]
        SGH09 & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\ghspic{aqpol}} & Danger pour l'environnement\\
        \bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
\caption{Pictogrammes dangers pour l'environnement}
\label{fig:picto_danger_environnement}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


